# setImageList in wxwidgets in setting image to all rows instead of just column header

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, listctrl

[image]I am trying to set up arrow and down arrow image to column header in wxlistcontrol,

After using listControl->setImageList. when sorting is called on the listcontrol. The image is being set to all row in the first column but what i need is just the image on column headers.How do I solve this

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the [listctrl sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/listctrl/listtest.cpp) already does exactly what you're trying to do. Build and run it to verify that it's really the case, then study its source code to see what it does.

Comment: I just checked the sample code for listcontrol even that the icons set for all the row in first column. I have added screenshot to the question which indicates 1 and 2. I do not want image at place 2

Comment: The code setting the column image is entirely different from the code setting the item images, they just happen to set the same image for both in the sample. Do look at `MyFrame::InitWithReportItems()` in the sample code.